# How to run fixture before mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

```
Sample_test.py

@pytest.mark.parametrize(argnames="key",argvalues=ExcelUtils.getinputrows(__name__),scope="session")
def test_execute():
    #Do something

conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(name='setup',autouse=True,scope="session")
def setup_test(pytestconfig):
    dict['environment']="QA"
```

As shown in the code above , I need to run the setup fixture before the test_execute method because the getinputrows method requires the environment to read the sheet. Unfortunately, the parametrize fixture gets executed before the setup_test. Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: `parametrize` is not a fixture, it's a decorator. Decorators are evaluated on module imports, where no function (including fixtures) has a chance to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the parameter inside the test function, not in the decorator:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("key", [ExcelUtils.getinputrows], scope="session")
def test_execute(key):
    key(__name__)
    #Do something
```

or bind `__name__` to the function call beforehand, but again, call the function inside your test:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("key", [lambda: ExcelUtils.getinputrows(__name__)], scope="session")
def test_execute(key):
    key()
    #Do something
```

Mind you I am not fully understanding what you're doing, so these examples might or might not make sense.

Comment: I need to run the fixture in confest.py before the test_execute method in the Sample_test.py !

Comment: Wait, do you want `setup_test()` to execute before `test_execute()` or before `ExcelUtils.getinputrows()`?

Comment: I want setup_test() to execute before test_execute().

Comment: I double checked. `setup_test()` executes before `test_execute()`

Comment: Sorry to say, but it doesn't. What it does is , it executes the getinputrows method in ExcelUtils class and then executes the setup_test method.

Comment: Can you add params from another class and check?

Comment: So you want `getinputrows()` to execute before `setup_test()`, not `test_execute()`. And as I said, that doesn't work. You need to call `getinputrows()` inside your tests.